# Login form issue vb.net

Tags: vb.net, authentication

I'm creating a student data management system and I'm stuck on the login form.
I've created a sign up form where the details entered are saved in a text file (Users.txt).
I can't seem to figure out what the problem is in the login form code (pasted below); it doesn't seem to recognise any saved login usernames and passwords.
Please help.
Thanks.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Registration

    Dim myfilewriter As StreamWriter
    Dim myfilereader As StreamReader
    Dim strMyFilename As String
    Dim intNumofRecs As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Structure Users
        Dim intUserID As Integer
        Dim strusername As String
        Dim strpassword As String
    End Structure
    Dim UsersArray() As Users
    Private Sub readindata()
        Dim intCounter As Integer
        strMyFilename = "Users.txt"
        myfilereader = New StreamReader(strMyFilename)
        intNumofRecs = myfilereader.ReadLine
        ReDim Preserve UsersArray(intNumofRecs)

        intCounter = 0

        Do Until myfilereader.EndOfStream = True
            intCounter = intCounter + 1
            UsersArray(intCounter).intUserID = myfilereader.ReadLine()
            UsersArray(intCounter).strusername = myfilereader.ReadLine()
            UsersArray(intCounter).strpassword = myfilereader.ReadLine()

        Loop

        myfilereader.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnNewUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewUser.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Sign_Up.Show()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Registration_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        readindata()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        Dim username As Boolean = False
        Dim password As Boolean = False
        Dim temp As String
        myfilereader = System.IO.File.OpenText("Users.txt")
        temp = myfilereader.ReadToEnd
        myfilereader.Close()

        If txtusername.Text = temp And txtpassword.Text = temp Then
            username = True
            password = True
        Else
            MsgBox("User not found")
        End If

        If username And password = True Then
            txtusername.Text = ""
            txtpassword.Text = ""
            Me.Hide()
            Dashboard.Show()
        Else
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

and below is the code for the sign up form (how the text is saved to the users.txt file):

```
Public Sub SavetoTextFile()
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    readindata()
    intNumofRecs = intNumofRecs + 1

    ReDim Preserve UsersArray(intNumofRecs)
    UsersArray(intNumofRecs).intUserID = intNumofRecs
    UsersArray(intNumofRecs).strusername = txtUsername.Text
    UsersArray(intNumofRecs).strpassword = txtPassword.Text

    strMyFilename = "Users.txt"
    myfilewriter = New StreamWriter(strMyFilename)
    myfilewriter.WriteLine(intNumofRecs)

    For intCounter = 1 To intNumofRecs
        myfilewriter.WriteLine(UsersArray(intCounter).intUserID)
        myfilewriter.WriteLine(UsersArray(intCounter).strusername)
        myfilewriter.WriteLine(UsersArray(intCounter).strpassword)
    Next
    myfilewriter.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSignUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignUp.Click
    SavetoTextFile()
    txtUsername.Text = ""
    txtPassword.Text = ""
    Me.Hide()
    Registration.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: `If txtusername.Text = temp And txtpassword.Text = temp Then` Do you expect that the username and the password are equal?  Also, I guess `Users.txt` probably have a few lines with several user/password, so you should search on that file. In order to help you is also important to tell us how is the info in `Users.txt` saved

Comment: Can I also add that your user.txt file data should(must) be encrypted.

Comment: @DavidWilson How can I encrypt the data?

Comment: @Pikoh Then text file does have several lines. It starts with the total number of users, followed by the user ID (starting from 1 and going up) and then followed by the username and then the password. How do I search for the username? I've added the code for how the text is saved to the file in the question above. Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is far too broad to post here, but a quick search of google using "vb.net encrypt user password text file" produces 750 thousand results - Have a look.

Comment: @DavidWilson I will do. But I'm sure that's 749,999 too many. LOL.